# Бот на пайтоне с сайтом

Tags: python, discord

пишу бота на пайтоне. Я хочу чтобы когда пользователь нажимал на ссылку (которая имеет параметр indentify в url generator) то на сайте переменная допустим name равнялась имени того кто зарегался с помощью ссылки. Вытворял подобную дичь на js, а как на пайтоне хз. Пожалуйста подскажите как это сделать или дайте ссылку на документацию, просто я ничего не нашел

Comment: python не работает в браузере клиента. Детализируйте вопрос, кто что и где нажимает, как и куда это передается, что где происходит и как это клиенту передается(или планируется преедаваться) и что за переменная name такая, она где инициализирована?